# angular component hover class dynamic

Tags: angular, components

I have an angular component which takes a parameter as input.  This parameter determines the class to apply if the user hovers over the element (its not if to apply the class or not, but the class name to apply when the user hovers over the element)

This is a small abbreviation of the component

```
 @Input() hoverClassName: string;
```

In the component I have a span element, how do I apply this class dynamically to the span element when the user hovers over the element, ideally I'm looking for something like this

```
<span (onMouseOverClass)="hoverClassName"/>
```

Is this something which can be done without a lot of .ts code?

Comment: You can use `ngClass` and the pseudo-class `:hover` to achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement it as demonstrated below:

**Component:**

```js
@Input() public hoverClassName: string;
public hovered: boolean;
```

**Template:**

```html
<span 
  (mouseover)="hovered = true"
  (mouseout)="hovered = false"
  [ngClass]="hovered && hoverClassName">
</span>
```